# Is it possible to collide two neutrons?

Tags: particle-physics, thermal-conductivity, neutrons, gamma-rays, particle-accelerators

If it is possible to collide two neutrons, how is it so? What particle accelerator or pre-collision processes are necessary and what results can be expected? If the products of neutron-neutron collisions are electrons, positrons and gamma rays, is it possible to transfer the resultant energy to another substance in order to make it thermal conductor or in short charge it?

Comment: Suggest you do some on-line research on neutron scattering experimental techniques, and then come back and ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called *neutron-neutron scattering* and the details can be found on the interwebs.

Note that because neutrons have no net charge, they cannot be accelerated like bullets in a particle accelerator and then aimed at a target. Instead, neutrons are created in an accelerator by shooting something at something else which then produces a bunch of neutrons, and filtering out everything but the resulting neutrons.

Those neutron bullets then get aimed at a target which is rich in neutrons that are bound up in nuclei and not *free* neutrons. The fact that the target neutrons are *bound* will affect the dynamics, see Rob's note below.

Note also that a neutron is really a collection of three quarks that are confined inside the thing we call a neutron. This means that when two neutrons collide, what is actually happening is that *generally* a quark inside one of the neutrons interacts with a quark inside the other. The specifics of that process are very complicated; see Vangi's note below.

The energies required to push one collection of quarks inside another is so great that both neutrons usually disintegrate and produce a shower of other particles that then go flying off. Sorting the pertinent signals out of that complicated mess is a hard job, but the particle people have figured out how to do it.

Comment: Re your fourth paragraph (v1): I'm not aware of any scattering experiment between *free* neutrons, especially at an energy which would create baryon excitations. There is a story about a (failed) experiment involving two simultaneous underground nuclear tests, which is either a myth, unpublished, or a state secret that I shouldn't have been told about. Otherwise it's mostly impossible to get enough neutron density to observe collisions, though there were some implausible proposals when I quit following the literature. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Wouldn't the preferred channel in neutron-neutron interaction be through gluons and non-valence quarks, as I think the valence quarks (udd) of neutrons are not able to interact with other valence quarks - e.g. you need a $\bar{u}$ for  a $u\bar{u}g$ vertex?

Comment: @rob, nope, except for what I read on-line. Will edit, thanks- Niels

Comment: @vangi, you are operating at a detail level I cannot. Please suggest specific edits to my answer, or post your own, as it is obvious you know a lot more about this than I do! best regards, Niels.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I am not stating something I am 100% certain of, hence the use of "I think..". The way I read the paragraph made me think that the only possible interaction is through the valence quarks and wondered whether that was the case or there was a contribution from the sea of quarks and gluons inside the neutron (it will probably depend on energy through the different parton distribution functions). I think the way you rephrased it avoids (at least my) confusion. Maybe someone else can confirm and/or shed more light. Cheers, Vangi

Comment: And then there are things like https://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.77.054002 probing the neutron-neutron scattering length in the course of a reaction.